# Credentials returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, credentials

Im using rails 5.2.8 and im trying to get the credentials I added to the file , I used the line

```
EDITOR="code --wait" rails credentials:edit
```

to open the file , and added those lines :

```
twitter:
  api_key: DWfZYmkgdogergojregk
  secret_key: o9dXeInlkfirefnbFGD
```

but when I try to reach theme using rails console

```
Rails.application.credentials.twitter
```

I always get the response nil , I tried so many ways

```
Rails.application.credentials[:twitter, :api_key]
Rails.application.credentials[:api_secret]
Rails.application.credentials.dig(Rails.env.to_sym, :api_key)
```

Comment: Strange behaviour. Have you try to manual specify the env? Like: `EDITOR="code --wait" rails credentials:edit --environment development` and `rails c --environment development`

Comment: actually Im following GoRails tutorial the first thing I did is  "--environment development" I did it so many times it keeps showing me this message :
ERROR: "rails edit" was called with arguments ["--environment", "development"]